# Filter array of objects if any key is falsy

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How can i filter array like that

```
[
    { foo: NaN, test: 'String' },
    { foo: 2, test: '' },
    { foo: 3, test: 'Something' },
]
```

and return a new array without objects where values of keys are falsy? In this case should return array only with third object.

```
[
    { foo: 3, test: 'Something' },
]
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: do you know the objects keys beforehand or the content may be arbitrary?

Comment: `Object.values()` + `Array.prototype.filter()` + `Array.prototype.some()`

Comment: What have you tried so far? A `for` loop with a `for...in...` and an `if` would also do the job.

Comment: @gbalduzzi  yes i know objects keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just filter and check all values of the objects.

```js
var array = [{ foo: NaN, test: 'String' }, { foo: 2, test: '' }, { foo: 3, test: 'Something' }],
    result = array.filter(o => Object.values(o).every(Boolean));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter and reduce

```js
const array = [
    { foo: NaN, test: 'String' },
    { foo: 2, test: '' },
    { foo: 3, test: 'Something' },
]


array.filter(item => Object.values(item).reduce((acc, value) => acc && value), true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop thru your array and add a condition like this:

```
var arr = [
        { foo: NaN, test: 'String' },
        { foo: 2, test: '' },
        { foo: 3, test: 'Something' },
    ]; // example data
var newarr=[];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i].foo && arr[i].test){
       newarr.push( arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps

Answer (score -1):

Foo = 2 is not falsy in this case, so it is included in output too.

```js
const data = [
        { foo: NaN, test: 'String' },
        { foo: 2, test: '' },
        { foo: 3, test: 'Something' },
    ];
    
console.log(data.filter(obj => obj.foo));
```

Comment: _"In this case should return array **only with third object**."_